# How to refresh AEM component in Author view after Edit?

Tags: reactjs, aem

Am new to Adobe Experience Manager. Your input on below question is highly appreciated!

All I am trying to do is: Refresh author page after making an update to AEM component. The component is built with React.

- Open the component dialog
- Change the value (for ex: Label)
- Click done from dialog
- Am expecting author page to load automatically

Please share your inputs. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The component doesn't refresh the entire page on save unless you explicitly configure it to. You can probably make use of the `cq:editConfig` for that. The `cq:editConfig` needs to have a child node `cq:listeners` with the property `afteredit`. Sample structure below

[image]

Some info around the edit config can be found in [this blogpost](http://www.sgaemsolutions.com/2019/01/ootbcustom-cqlisteners-in-cqeditconfig.html).